# How to convert list of tuples to tuple of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to convert list of tuples to tuple of tuples , what I am doing is wrong, Please help to fix this issue

```
list1= [('2', '297'), ('6', '297')]

for x in list1:
    print("inside fn")
    print(x)
    tuple_of_tuples+=tuple(x)
    print(tuple_of_tuples)
```

output = `('2', '297', '6', '297')`
I want output as `(('2', '297'), ('6', '297'))`

Comment: `tuple(list1)` should do

Comment: your mistake: `tuple_of_tuples+=(x,)`. But underperformant like hell.

Comment: thanks for correcting my mistake. am even below underperformant!

Answer (score 5):

```
In [1]: list1= [('2', '297'), ('6', '297')]

In [2]: tuple(list1)
Out[2]: (('2', '297'), ('6', '297'))
```

Comment: tuple(list1) is not working for the below list,  list1=[('2','297)] , tuple(list1) is giving the o/p as (('2', '297'),) , why it is coming like this? how to get the o/p as (('2','297)) ?

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: The comma is what makes the tuple, the parentheses are only needed for disambiguation. A single-element tuple is denoted by a comma. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Thanks for your help, am a beginner.